# MySQL - How to Get Duplicate Data Appearing in Different Rows for Specific User

Tags: mysql, duplicate-data

I'm having difficulties in designing a specific Mysql query. What I need is getting duplicate data like 'spending' across different campaign names of specific user.

For ex, assume I have this username: "John"
And John has several campaign names associated with him in the same Table.
For each campaign name, he has different 'spending' data like: $550, $660, $675 etc.

What I want is to get the duplicate 'spending' data that appears across John 'campaigns'

So, if $600 appears in all John campaigns: 'campagin1', 'camapgin2', 'camapgin3' then I want that data returned.

All data is found in one table.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can select all rows and then for each row select all rows which have the same spending column value

Answer (score 0):

`assuming your table structure`

```
select spending_data,campaign_num,count(username) as duplicates  from table 
    having count(username) >1
    group by spending_data,campaign_num
```